# Cannot get phantomjs to login to DEV paypal account -

Tags: paypal, webdriver, phantomjs, paypal-sandbox

I am attempting to login to the DEV PAYPAL site using phantomJS.

On clicking the login button from the popup I am seeing the following error message

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error Message => 'Click succeeded but Load Failed. Status: 'fail''
 caused by Request => {"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, image/png","Connection":"Keep-Alive","Content-Length":"27","Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","Host":"localhost:55458"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"id\":\":wdc:1371206664100\"}","url":"/click","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"click","directory":"/","path":"/click","relative":"/click","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/click","queryKey":{},"chunks":["click"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/5e4434e0-d4df-11e2-941a-e76337e4cf88/element/%3Awdc%3A1371206664100/click"}
Command duration or timeout: 7.12 seconds
Build info: version: '2.32.0', revision: '6c40c18', time: '2013-04-09 17:22:56'
System info: os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.6.0_25-ea'
Session ID: 5e4434e0-d4df-11e2-941a-e76337e4cf88
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver
Capabilities [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=false, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=phantomjs, rotatable=false, driverVersion=1.0.3, locationContextEnabled=false, version=1.9.0, databaseEnabled=false, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=false, browserConnectionEnabled=false, proxy={proxyType=direct}, webStorageEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, driverName=ghostdriver, applicationCacheEnabled=false, takesScreenshot=true}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:268)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:79)
    at com.selenium.wipro.Phantomsample.ExampleScenario.main(ExampleScenario.java:114)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ScreenshotException: Screen shot has been taken
Build info: version: '2.32.0', revision: '6c40c18', time: '2013-04-09 17:22:56'
System info: os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.6.0_25-ea'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:125)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: Error Message => 'Click succeeded but Load Failed. Status: 'fail''
 caused by Request => {"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, image/png","Connection":"Keep-Alive","Content-Length":"27","Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","Host":"localhost:55458"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"id\":\":wdc:1371206664100\"}","url":"/click","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"click","directory":"/","path":"/click","relative":"/click","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/click","queryKey":{},"chunks":["click"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/5e4434e0-d4df-11e2-941a-e76337e4cf88/element/%3Awdc%3A1371206664100/click"}
Build info: version: '2.32.0', revision: '6c40c18', time: '2013-04-09 17:22:56'
System info: os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.6.0_25-ea'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

I am using phantomjs 1.9.0 through the JAVA WebDriver.

I have done a lot of reading and have tried setting the following capability

```
DesiredCapabilities PJScapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.phantomjs();
PJScapabilities.setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);
PJScapabilities.setCapability("secureSsl", true);
PJScapabilities.setCapability("acceptSslCerts", true);
PJScapabilities.setCapability("javascriptEnabled", true );
//Need to set an environmental variable that points to the location of the PhantomJS Binary for GhostDriver support
//D:\workspace\phantomjs
PJScapabilities.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, "D:\\workspace\\phantomjs\\phantomjs.exe");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug with GhostDriver. See:

https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/202